# Embed the sample files of F# JsonProvider to use in a library

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

According [to this](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html), you can specify samples as embedded resources by using EmbeddedResource:

```
type Declaracion = JsonProvider<"declaracion.json", EmbeddedResource="Irpf.Hechos, declaracion.json">
```

But when I reference this library, "Irpf.Hechos.dll", I get a File Not Found error, the path ConsumingLibraryPath\declaracion.json is not found; typecheck error FS3033

I have tried to set the declaracion.json file as resource, and content, but no luck.

Am I missing some step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the build action as "**Embedded**Resource" rather than "Resource".

Comment: This solve the issue. Anyway it is a bit annoying that each change needs to remove and add the reference again.